# Using XAML and Silverlight 4, is there a way to build up a dynamic GRID rows and columns from databinding?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, dynamic, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to have a regular grid rows and columns defined dynamically using databinding in XAML only.

I know I can use code behind for this but I'm looking for a way to do it purely in XAML.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe post how you're doing it in code behind.  My question is what the datasource looks like.  Will it have data annotations for the column names?  Where does auto generate columns fail you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after much reading around the net I coded the following solution:

```cs
public class DynamicGrid : Grid
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register ("NumColumns", typeof (int), typeof (DynamicGrid), 
        new PropertyMetadata ((o, args) => ((DynamicGrid)o).RecreateGridCells()));

    public int NumColumns
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(NumColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue (NumColumnsProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumRowsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NumRows", typeof(int), typeof(DynamicGrid),
        new PropertyMetadata((o, args) => ((DynamicGrid)o).RecreateGridCells()));

    public int NumRows
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(NumRowsProperty); }
        set { SetValue (NumRowsProperty, value); }
    }

    private void RecreateGridCells()
    {
        int numRows = NumRows;
        int currentNumRows = RowDefinitions.Count;

        while (numRows > currentNumRows)
        {
            RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            currentNumRows++;
        }

        while (numRows < currentNumRows)
        {
            currentNumRows--;
            RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(currentNumRows);
        }

        int numCols = NumColumns;
        int currentNumCols = ColumnDefinitions.Count;

        while (numCols > currentNumCols)
        {
            ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            currentNumCols++;
        }

        while (numCols < currentNumCols)
        {
            currentNumCols--;
            ColumnDefinitions.RemoveAt(currentNumCols);
        }

        UpdateLayout();
    }
}
```

It works but I'm not sure it is the optimal solution. Any comments on this one?